# Segmentation fault after using free for 3 times in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C.These codes are for educational purpose.
please compile the files together by:
`gcc main.c api.c interruptStruct.h -o x`

In the `main.c` file , I called the `interrupt_generate` function 3 times, calling the function 2 times don't give any error.

when i run the file `x` it gives a segmentation fault and i think this is also due using `free`  in  `interrupt_generate` function given in the file `api.c` .

I don't know why these is happening. Does anyone know why ?

There are 3 files given below:

1. interruptStruct.h

```
typedef struct {
    int uid;
    int priority;
    int *address;
} InterruptService;

typedef struct {
    InterruptService *stack;
    int stack_type;
} StackFrame;

void freed(StackFrame *Sframe);

void interrupt_generate(StackFrame *process_stackFrame,StackFrame *store_stackFrame,int uid,int priority,int *address);

void init_stackFrame(StackFrame *Sframe,int type);

void push(StackFrame *Sframe,InterruptService *interrupt,int *count);

void print_stackFrame(StackFrame *Sframe);
```

3. api.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "interruptStruct.h"

int process_count = 0;
int store_count = 0;

void freed(StackFrame *main_stack)
{
    free(main_stack->stack);
    main_stack->stack = NULL;
}

void init_stackFrame(StackFrame *main_stack,int type)
{
    main_stack->stack = (InterruptService *) malloc(sizeof(InterruptService));
    main_stack->stack_type = type;
}

void push(StackFrame *main_stack,InterruptService *interrupt,int *count)
{
    if(*count!=0)
    {
        main_stack->stack = (InterruptService *) realloc(main_stack->stack,sizeof(InterruptService*)*(*count+1));
    }
    main_stack->stack[*count] = *interrupt;
    *count += 1;
}

void print_stackFrame(StackFrame *stackframe)
{   
    int count;
    if(stackframe->stack_type==0)
    {
        count = store_count;
    }
    else{
        count = process_count;
    }   
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("\nInterrupt id : %d\n",stackframe->stack[i].uid);
        printf("Interrupt priority : %d\n",stackframe->stack[i].priority);
        printf("Interrupt address : %p\n",stackframe->stack[i].address);
    }
    printf("------------------------\n\n"); 
}

void interrupt_generate(StackFrame *process_stackFrame,StackFrame *store_stackFrame,int uid,int priority,int *loc)
{   
    InterruptService *interrupt;
    interrupt = (InterruptService *)malloc(sizeof(InterruptService));
    interrupt->uid = uid;
    interrupt->priority = priority;
    interrupt->address = loc;
    if(process_count==0)
    {
        push(process_stackFrame,interrupt,&process_count);
    }
    else
    {
        if(process_stackFrame->stack[process_count-1].priority < interrupt->priority)
        {
            push(store_stackFrame,process_stackFrame->stack,&store_count);
            process_count = 0;
            push(process_stackFrame,interrupt,&process_count);
        }
        else{
            push(store_stackFrame,interrupt,&store_count);
        }
    }
    free(interrupt);
    interrupt=NULL;
}
```

2. main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "interruptStruct.h"

int main()
{
    StackFrame process_stackFrame,store_stackFrame;
    init_stackFrame(&process_stackFrame,1);
    init_stackFrame(&store_stackFrame,0);

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;

    interrupt_generate(&process_stackFrame,&store_stackFrame,1,1,&a);
    interrupt_generate(&process_stackFrame,&store_stackFrame,2,2,&b);
    interrupt_generate(&process_stackFrame,&store_stackFrame,3,3,&c);
    
    printf("Process stack : \n");
    print_stackFrame(&process_stackFrame);
    printf("Storage stack : \n\n");
    print_stackFrame(&store_stackFrame);

    freed(&process_stackFrame);
    freed(&store_stackFrame);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. At a minimum that will give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault.

Comment: Check the return value from `malloc()`?

Comment: @Andrew the malloc is pointing to a memory block

Comment: I have taken a quick glance at your code, but it takes more time to understand than I am typically willing to spend. To but it bluntly, the code is ugly. The fact that you store the stack size in global variables, and have this weird `stack_type` member in `StackFrame` which tells which global variable to use is hard to follow. Get rid of`stack_type`, and put a `count` member in `StackFrame`. You should also implement other stack primitives like `top`, `pop` etc. and use those rather than accessing members of `StackFrame` directly.

Comment: @underscore_d stack_type is used onlt to differentiate between process_stack and store_stack

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out, In ```api.c``` , in the reallocation part , its ```sizeof(InterruptService)``` not ```sizeof(InterruptService*)```, that's the part for which I was getting ```segmentation fault```.